# How to load a script only for mobile on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I'm trying to make load a simple javascript code on wordpress just on mobile in header.

I've tried plugins and to code but It seems not within my reach and need help :D

Ciao!

Comment: (I mean on header.php obviously)

Answer (score 6):

```
function custom_load_scripts() { 
   // Load if not mobile 
   if ( ! wp_is_mobile() ) { 
      // Example script 
      wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name',get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array (), '1.0.0', true ); 
      } 
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_load_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have suggested using the WordPress function `wp_is_mobile()` when enqueuing a script. Be very careful doing this. If you use caching plugins or if your host caches PHP requests, this could make this method useless.

Instead, I would recommend loading the JavaScript file and testing to see if the browser is mobile or not based on the screen size of the device using JavaScript.

Here is an example (uses jQuery):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {      
    var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)");

    if (isMobile.matches) {
        //Add your script that should run on mobile here
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be adding JS (or CSS) files directly to your `header.php` or `footer.php` files.

What you can do instead is enqueue and dequeue scripts and styles use the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook.

Inside a function on that hook, you'll add scripts using the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function. Setting the 5th argument to `true` will put the code in the header.

You'll note the 3rd argument is an array, that's an array of scripts that your code is dependent on, such as if your code relies on jQuery, you could change that to `array( 'jquery' )`

Lastly, WordPress has a function to detect mobile devices that works relatively well, conveniently called [`wp_is_mobile()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/).

So we can just check if that returns `true` before we enqueue our script.

Place this code in your `functions.php` file, of course after replacing the URL with the URL to your script.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jung_mobile_only_js');
function jung_mobile_only_js(){
    if( wp_is_mobile() ){
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jung-mobile-only-js', 'URL_TO_YOUR_JS_FILE_HERE', array(), '1.0', true );
    }
}
```